# When exactly does Try become Catch?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have this Try / Catch block that tries using Stripe to process a payment. I wanted to check that if there's an error in the Charge::create method that the rest of the code in the TRY block won't continue to execute? Otherwise my DB would be updated and the customer would be emailed even though their payment didn't go through.

Please can someone clarify the behaviour of Try / Catch for me?

```
try {
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $charge_amount, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => CURRENCY,
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => $description,
    "receipt_email" => $email,
    "metadata" => $metadata)
  );

//adjust inventory
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item => $quantity)
{
  $db->query("UPDATE stock SET stock = stock - '$quantity', reserved = reserved + '$quantity' WHERE id = '$item'");
}
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
//update cart
$db->query("UPDATE cart SET paid = 1 WHERE id = '$cart_id'");

blah blah, lots of other stuff...

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  echo $e;
}
```

Comment: Becomes a catch when an exception is thrown. After the catch you can also add a finally which will always execute no matter if  exception is thrown or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, exactly that.

A try...catch block in (almost) any progamming language will basically TRY to run the code inside your block, but will stop when it encounters an error (specifically an exception), and that will be CAUGHT and handled as directed - assuming the catch block is run successfully, execution will then continue after the end of the try...catch block (unless you exit the execution as part of your catch statement).

Comment: What programming language is this not true in?

Comment: nickb - Common Lisp allows you to pick up from exactly where you left off in the stack - for example if you had a 'File Not Found' exception, the exception handler might create the file, and execution continues on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Try becomes catch when an error is thrown.  This means that if the \Stripe\Charge::Create method fails, it will immediately go to your catch block and bypass the DB update, the customer email and all the rest.

With that said, you probably still want to do some more checking in your code between the charge to your customer and your other processing.  At the very least check that $charge->paid == true.  To be more careful (we are talking money here) check that livemode is true, that the currency is your currency (dollars?) and that the amount is what you expected.

Check out Larry Ullman's site about how to handle stripe errors for more information:
http://www.larryullman.com/2013/01/30/handling-stripe-errors/

Also:
http://www.larryullman.com/2013/01/09/writing-the-php-code-to-process-payments-with-stripe/